# Why is Python extended slicing returning an unexpected number of elements?

Tags: python, slice

I have two files, `x.py` with the following code:

```
import fileinput

lines = fileinput.input()
i = int(lines[0])
print(i)
lst = [int(k) for k in lines[1][:i:2]]
print(lst)
```

and `test1.in` with the contents:

```
4
3 4 2 8
```

If I execute `cat test1.in | python3 x.py` I get the following output:

```
4
[3, 4]
```

When I expect the last line to be `[3, 4, 2, 8]` since I thought a slice that is essentially `[0:4:2]` would select 4 elements, slicing 2 at a time. Is this incorrect? Can you propose an alternative solution that would be correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[0:4:2] -> select 0 to 3 with a step of two -> items 0 and 2`

Comment: `lines[1][0]=='3'`, `lines[1][1]==' '`, `lines[1][2]=='4'`. You are selecting the items from `0` inclusive to `4` exclusive, going `2` at a time. That's items 0 (`'3'`) and 2 (`'4'`). If you want more elements, you could use the slice `[:i*2:2]`

Comment: You could have cut out all the irrelevant file reading and posted a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you, Moses - if you submit this as an answer I would love to select you as best answer! As well as you khelwood, although Moses was faster :)